# href pulling linked text away from main text

Tags: css

Please view this [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/uwLKw/embedded/result/)

This is a jquery notification tab that goes at the top of a page.

You'll notice some text that should say...

"Would you like a guided tour of the Grad Team Cloud? Click here!", except that the "here" part has fallen off and is floating right. It is wrapped with an href.

Because it's in an href, it's abiding by this CSS...

```
.sticky p, .floated p, .fixed p, .ondemand p{ float:left; padding:0px; margin:0px; margin-left:40px; line-height:45px; color:#fff; font-size:18px; width: 70%; }

.sticky a { float:right; margin:13px 10px 0px 0px; }
```

The 'X' (close button) in the corner is also aligned with this CSS, so adjusting it will cause issues.

I tried applying an in-line style `style="float: left;"` to the href, but it didn't work either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you only want the close button to float right, and all other a tags should be inline.  If so, you can change this:

```
.sticky a, .floated a, .fixed a, .ondemand a{ float:right; margin:13px 10px 0px 0px; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

to this:

```
.sticky a, .floated a, .fixed a, .ondemand a{margin:13px 10px 0px 0px; color: #FFFFFF; }
a.close {float:right;}
```

Comment: You nailed it Andi! Thanks!